# Is it possible to make neovim use single color for underline?

Tags: neovim, terminal, highlight, tmux, alacritty

As title. With my current setup it looks like this:

[image]

But I only want it to use a single color. My current highlight setup:

```lua
:hi IndentBlanklineContextStart
IndentBlanklineContextStart xxx cterm=underline gui=underline guisp=#fb5e2a
```

And, what makes me confused is that this problem only occurs when my neovim is running inside a tmux session. If I run neovim directly without tmux session I got expected behaviour:

[image]

Comment: What's the value of `echo $TERM` (executed from bash) in outside _and_ inside tmux?

Comment: @kadekai: Thanks for your help :) The result of it inside/outside tmux are both `alacritty`. Not intended to do things in a rush but I also asked the same question on both tmux and alacritty's GitHub repos and got the answer. So hopefully this comment will save your time to help more people :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer will only be useful for those who also have this environment setup:

- You use Alacritty as terminal simulator. (since it support coloring of underlines.)
- Running neovim inside a tmux session.

When I tried to solve this problem I wasn't sure about the source of it. It turns out this is not related to vi/vim(so sorry about posting it here...), and we only need to add one line in `tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -ga terminal-features ",alacritty:usstyle"
```

If you want to read more context, this is the related [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/issues/6424):